# Update table_A value based on table_B in Derby

Tags: sql, derby, multiple-tables

I've got two tables:

table A

```
PK   TBL_A_ID   ITEM
0001 12345678   apple
0002 23456789   banana
```

table B

```
PK   TBL_A_ID   DESTINATION
0001 12345678   Boston
0002 23456789   London
0003 23456789   Rome
0004 12345678   Beijing
```

I want to change table B DESTINATION to "Shanghai" if the ITEM is "banana".

table B (expected result)

```
PK   TBL_A_ID   DESTINATION
0001 12345678   Boston
0002 23456789   Shanghai
0003 23456789   Shanghai
0004 12345678   Beijing
```

Can it be done with one one line of statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
update table_b set destination='shanghai' 
  where tbl_a_id = (select tbl_a_id from table_a where  item='banana')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Table_B set Destination = 'Shanghai'
from Table_A a Join Table_B b on
a.TBL_A_ID = B.TBL_A_ID
where a.Item = 'Banana'
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, I don't believe Derby supports the update-from syntax